# How to get gdb to display memory offsets

Tags: assembly, gdb

I have created the following stub assembly program to demonstrate this:

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov $4,  %edi
    mov $60, %eax
    syscall
```

And I have generated the executable with (gas):

```
$ as file.s -o file.o
$ ld file.o -o file
```

And then entered gdb with:

```
$ gdb file
>>> starti
```

And my terminal looks like:

[image]

However, if I disassemble it, it gives me the proper memory offsets instead of the `?` every time:

```
>>> disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
=> 0x0000000000400078 <+0>: mov    $0x4,%edi
   0x000000000040007d <+5>: mov    $0x3c,%eax
   0x0000000000400082 <+10>:    syscall
End of assembler dump.
>>>
```

Is there something I need to add to the assembler or linker commands so that `gdb` can read the offset?

Comment: That looks like a bug in whatever fancy gdb customization you use (unless it's a feature of newer gdb than what I have). Anyway, if it knows you are in `_start` then it should be able to print the offsets.

Comment: @Jester I see -- are there any flags in `as` that you can use to add in (more) debug information?

Comment: No, all the debug info is clearly there since disassembly shows it, and even your broken fancy output knows what `_start` is. It's your custom gdb that is broken.